# HTML table exceeds browser's width

Tags: html, css

I've created a table containing 180 columns of number of days in 6 months and I want the table to be fitted in the browser's width.

I've tried CSS `max-width="100%"` and `style="width: 100%;"`, but none of them works.

Are there any other ways I should try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you used this property `table-layout: fixed;` and ` white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: If the contents of your table exceed the width of the browser.. the table will expand to fit the contents inside. Have you checked you haven't got widths inside the table that are pushing it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the table layout you have to use `table-layout: fixed;`. also make sure don't use `px` value in `td` and if the text is too long you can use below property for `td`. so table layout remain same.

```
table{table-layout: fixed;}

td{ text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```